# SQL Server 2012 Maintenance Plan can't modify

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Click on any created Maintenance Plan:**
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: component (System.Design)
 BUTTONS:OK

---

**Create a new Plan I get this error:**

TITLE: Maintenance Plan Wizard Progress
Saving maintenance plan failed.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: The SaveToSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80004005 (Unspecified error).  The SQL statement that was issued has failed.

The SaveToSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80004005 (Unspecified error).  The SQL statement that was issued has failed.

BUTTONS:OK

---

**Edit an already created Backup Plan:**
Error 1 Error loading 'BackupDb' : The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80004005 (Unspecified error).  The SQL statement that was issued has failed.  . server=SERVER;package=Maintenance Plans\BackupLeadsDb; 1 1

Attemped Solutions:   I've changed password for SA Account; I use Windows Authentication to log in; and I've registered  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTS.dll.  Repair SQL Server 2012, Uninstall/ReInstall SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on my local machine, I get the same issue trying to modify a backup plan on a SQL2008r2 server.

It works with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio2008r2 on both my local PC and directly RDPing on to the server and running SSMS2008r2 from there.

Looks like a bug in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio2012 to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing something that is by design. SQL Server 2012 introduced a new designer for maintenance plans so if you try and edit a earlier version of a maintenance plan with SSMS 2012 it will be saved in the new format, then the lesser versions of SSMS will not be able to open it.

Reference [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995351%28v=sql.15%29.aspx), point 5.5:

> **5.5 New Maintenance Plan Layout Not Compatible with Earlier SQL Server Tools Issue**:
>  When SQL Server 2012 management tools are used to modify
>   an existing maintenance plan created in a previous version of SQL
>   Server management tools (SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008, or SQL
>   Server 2005), the maintenance plan is saved in a new format. Earlier
>   versions of SQL Server management tools do not support this new
>   format.
>
> **Workaround**: None